# Integrate StyleCops with SonarQube and display the results in SonarQube dashboard

Tags: c#, gitlab, sonarqube, stylecop

i want to integrate StyleCops with SonarQube and display the results in SonarQube dashboard. Started working on a POC. Now im stuck due to lack resources and domain experts.

I have some doubts.

1)Is it possible to achieve this with Community EDITION or do i need to request for a Developer or Enterprise edition.

2)Can we integrate gitlab .net project to SonarQube and analyze using StyleCop rules (C#)

Can someone guide me to achieve this. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if community edition allows but it works on enterprise edition. You just need to reference Stylecops in your project and when SonarQube scans the project it will import